# How to test a real ECU via canoe?

Tags: vector, simulation, ethernet, diagnostics, canoe

I want to do test a real ECU using VN5610A and CANoe.ethernet. the Vector hardware Config set up like this:

[image]

When send the diagnostic request to the real ECU, it cannot reach the real ECU. The trace window showed:

[image]

The DoIP/HFSZ settings looks like:
[image]

the setting for TCP/IP stack:

[image]

Port Configuration under Hardware:

[image]

Comment: Why do you setup up simulated nodes when you have real nodes and apparently want to talk to the real nodes and not the simulated ones?

Comment: How can I talk to the real node? I want to send diagnostic request to the real node, but I find i can just send request via diagnostic console, thus i need to simulate this real node in the simulation setup. And then deactivate it. Is it correct? Or do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance. @M.Spiller

Comment: Adding a node in the simulation setup is only necessary when you want to simulate something. You say that you can already send a request to the real ECU via the diagnostic console. Is that correct? You see the request in the trace and the answer as well? If yo, CAPL should also work. It would be good, if you could edit the question with (at least) screenshot of the diagnostic configuration dialog and the request you want to send.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain it clearly. I want to send diagnostic request to the real node via Canoe, but until now I did not find a correct way to do that. I suspected the connection of the real ECU, but if i send diagnostic request from en external tool, I can see request and response in the trace. So the real ECU is connected to the ethernet VN5610A. Now what i am doing is try to send request to the real ECU via CANoe. Do you have any idea? @M.Spiller

Comment: As you can see messages in the trace, your network setup seems to be correct. So just add a diagnostic description to the correct bus and configure the ECU address in the diagnostic configuration dialog. That should give you a diagnostic console which you can use to talk to the ECU. No need for anything in the remaining bus simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried it before. but when I choose  a request from the Diagnostic console and click send. The online/offline mode always shows "offline". I am in real bus mode. And got error in the trace window (the destination shows: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF). I cannot attach the picture here. But i edit the question now. how can i solve it? @M.Spiller

Comment: Still don't know how you have configured the ECU in the diagnostic configuration dialog. Mostly the DOIP/HsFZ settings are of interest

Comment: The only IP address I can config in Diagnostics/ISO TP Configuration is the "adapter" under "Tester". The pc IP address is e.x. 198.19.60,1, and the VN5610A IP address set 198.19.60.204, so I set the adapter's IP 198.19.60.204. Is it correct?

Comment: Could you show, what you have in the DoIP/HSFZ settings?

Comment: Yes, i put it in the question. the settings is automated got when i add the diagnostic description. the logical address to ECU and tester is correct. I just chose the adpater's IP address.

Comment: Looks good, although the layout of the dialog is a bit different to my version of CANoe. Hard to tell what is wrong without being able to click around in CANoe. Mask of /24 for the tester might be a culprit, as your other IP address seems to be in network 198.19.56.0 and which is not in 198.19.60.204/24.
Also you should check the settings in the TCP/IP stacks dialog, both for the Tester and AUD.

Comment: 198.19.56.0 is the SOME/IP network as I understand. Maybe TCP/IP stacks is an issue. I set 198.19.60.204 as the IP address for Eth 1 and the MAC address of the channel in VN5610A which is using now as the MAC address for Eth 1, is it correct? But how can set it for the AUD? Please see the picture of this setting in the question.

Comment: CANoe acts as the DoIP tester. So it has to be able to communicate with the ECU. They have to be in the same subnet. Which IP does your ECU have? Is it really in 198.19.60.204/24? For AUD, you do not really have to set something, as it should be found during DoIPs vehicle identification.

Comment: The IP address of the ECU is 198.19.60.203; my PC's IP address is 198.19.60.2,  and I set VN5610A, as well as the the DoIP tester's IP address as 198.19.60.204.

Comment: That all looks good. In the trace you have posted above, we can see the vehicle identification requests sent by CANoe, but no answer.
As a last resort, maybe, make sure to disconnect your external tool and reset the ECU. Try to sent something from CANoe again after that. Most DoIP ECUs do not respond to a second identification request once they are connected to a tester. If that also does not help, enter the ECUs IP address into the field "Address" on the DoIP/HSFZ page. Normally that should not be necessary, but maybe your ECU does not properly handle the identification requests.

Comment: I am sure I have closed all the other external tool. But do you think the tester sending request to the correct IP address? because the Destination address we can see in the trace for the DoIP Messeage is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF. Is it correct? And it is correctly send, we should see what kinds of DID I have sent.

Comment: I add the ECUs IP address in the the "Address" filed under "Vehicle Identification Request Parameter" and send request. please see the trace window i updated in the question. I changed the layout. It looks like the tester has communication with the ECU now. But did not work as i want.

Comment: Please also have a look the port configuration i attached in the question. Is it OK?

Comment: Sending to FF:FF... is ok, as it is a broadcast. The tester tries to find out which DoIP ECUs are available. The ECUs should respond with a vehicle announcement. After that the tester will create a connection to the ECU. In your latest trace there is at least some communication between tester and ECU on port 13900. Unfortunately your trace does not show the data that is exchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. @M.Spiller I have the last question about the hardware config. Please look at the question, in the application of the hardware config, CANoe has not been asigned to any channel of the Ethernet. And when i right click of the two channels, nothing can be chosen. could it be the problem?

Comment: There is a ethernet connection from CANoe to the ECU. You can see it in the trace you have attached; packages are exchanged between them. The "problem" is rather, that the ECU is closing or not accepting the connection with CANoe. You can see the `RST, ACK` TCP package in the trace you have attached.

Comment: Since the ECU can receive diagnostic request and send response with other external tools, so it should not being closing. right? When I send diagnostic requests via CANoe, the diagnostic message just communicated between my PC (198.19.60.2) and the real ECU (198.19.60.203). But i think it should be communicated between 198.19.60.203 and 198.19.60.204 (ethernet or tester). Is it something wrong here? i attached the trace in the question.

Comment: Your ECU might be configured to only accept requests from a certain IP-/MAC-Address. You might need to "authenticate" via CAN first, and so on.
The source of the DoIP requests is (or should be) the adapter which is selected in the diagnostic configuration dialog.
Without being able to see the whole system it is unfortunately nearly impossible to help you here.